# Why can't I use Phonegap's navigator object in launch function in Sencha touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

This is weird, I can use Phonegap's navigator object fine if I click a button on my page like so.

**Controller**

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            homeButton: 'button[action=viewHome]',
        },
        control: {
            homeButton: {
                tap: 'showHome'
            },
        }
    },  
    showHome: function(button, e, options) {
        navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
    },}
```

But if I try to access the navigator object in the launch function I get 'undefined'.

**Controller**

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    launch: function(){
        navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
    },}
```

The same thing is happening in app.js's launch function. Anybody know why is that and how I can use Phonegap in the launch function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to access the phonegap 'navigator' API, before it is ready. You have to listen for the deviceready event and once its triggered, you can call navigator.

You can call it this way.

```
launch: function () {
    if(Ext.browser.is.PhoneGap && !Ext.os.is.Desktop) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.mainLaunch, false);
    } else {
        this.mainLaunch();
    }
},

mainLaunch: function() {
    navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
}
```

The Ext.browser check is to make this work on chrome browser also, otherwise you will have to always test the app on Simulator, or device.